# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID

Tags: android, string, exception, resources, locale

Application throws an exception

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID

My case wasn't that common (since given ID does exist). I asked this question to answer it by myself.

Please see below my answer why could this happen and why it happend for me.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You maybe already found that this error happens when you are trying to set some integer as a string like:
somewhere in the code `some_variable` was declared as `int` and you want to show its value so you are trying to set it to `some_textview` using `setText()` method:

```
int some_variable = 0;
TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.someTextView);
... some code/calculations etc...
txtView.setText(some_variable); // exception! some_variable is an int value
```

also it could be a result returned by any method which returns int as a result, like:

```
txtView.setText(someString.length());// exception! String.length() returns an int value
txtView.setText(someSet.size());// exception! Set.size() returns an int value
```

etc.

these causes the `Resources$NotFoundException` cuz there is no `String` resource with such number (id).
As you most probably know at every build time there is a `R.java` file being created in build folder. This file contains static variables where every declared in string.xml `String` has its own unique *id* with some int value and this *id* you use in code as R.string.*id*. This is the reason of exception - system will try to find R.string.*id* string corresponding to given value but obviously fails in most cases. Also this is a reason why setText() accepts integer values and IDE don't warn you.
In some cases it could happen that your `some_variable` by chance will have a value which corresponds to some *id*. These are tricky cases because no exception will be thrown and you will see some unexpected text (actually corresponding to R.string.*id*) instead of variable value.
 
The solution to this issue is simple (if `some_variable`'s value must be shown):

```
txtView.setText(String.valueOf(some_variable));
```

There are also a number of people who are trying to set the `int` value in the same manner to the `Toast` message like:

```
int some_variable = 0;
... some code/calculations etc...
Toast.makeText(this, some_variable, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), someSet.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

The fix is the same:

```
int some_variable = 0;
... some code/calculations etc...
Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(some_variable), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), String.valueOf(some_Set.size()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

You maybe met approach which uses `Integer(some_variable).toString()` method. Its not bad. However this means 1 extra operation (wrapping int value to Integer) will be applied and that only integer value could be used (or `NumberFormatException` will be thrown) while for `String.valueOf(some_variable)` value type doesn't matter, it works for any type of value, including all primitives (float, double, byte, long etc) and will never throw any exception.
   Also there are some other cases - [rare cases are described here](http://android.konreu.com/developer-how-to/resources-notfoundexception/) and the point is to clean the project in IDE.
   In case if you are pretty sure you don't pass any integers in a manner described above and moreover this happens with released app and did not happen while developing it could be a `Locale` case. If your app has `Locale` depending `String` resources and when you tested it you probably did it using your region specific `Locale` device(s) and thus no issues was detected. However (bear in mind!) in such case you must provide a default `strings.xml` located in `res\values` folder of a project and if you missed it this is the case. Assume some user, lets say, from a Germany (who's device default `Locale` is DE) tries to run such app which only has `strings.xml` in folders `values-en` and `values-it` (but there is no `strings.xml` in `values` nor in `values-de` folders). In this case app will try to locate `values-de\strings.xml` first but fails, then it will try to use default `values\strings.xml` and fails once again so it will crash throwing `Resources$NotFoundException`.
The fix for this issue is, like I mentioned before, to provide a default `strings.xml` in `res\values` folder of a project so for any unsupported locale the default one will be used (usually english). Another way is to set a proper default locale for your app at run time (in Application extended class for instance) if it runs on a device with unsupported locale, like (assume you want to use `en` locale by default):

```
    Locale locale = getAppLocale(context);
    String localeLang = locale.getLanguage();
    // default locale is EN but available are EN and RU
    if (!localeLang.equalsIgnoreCase("en") && !localeLang.equalsIgnoreCase("ru")) {
        locale = new Locale("en");
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;

    context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
```

Comment: Perfect! mine was the language folder case!

Answer (score 0):

Just use String.valueOf(your_value_here)
this error usually occur when you are trying to set int data type in a textview but try the String.valueOf() function.