# AndroidStudios onClick Error

Tags: java, android

Hi Im new to androidStudios but this is probably really simple but im not sure why this doesn't work.

this is the error coming out:

```
                                 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22260)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22260) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
               Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x5
                  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:331)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getText(ResourcesWrapper.java:52)
                  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4550)
                  at jackiec.downloadmanagerapp.MainActivity.print(MainActivity.java:44)
                  at jackiec.downloadmanagerapp.MainActivity.add(MainActivity.java:38)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22260) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

activty_Main.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="jackiec.downloadmanagerapp.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:text="enter"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Enter"
            android:onClick="add"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Please enter a download speed:"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/speed"
            android:layout_below="@+id/server"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Enter the probability of new Regular job:"
            android:ems="10"
            android:layout_below="@+id/probP"
            android:id="@+id/probR"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="enter a probability of new premium job:"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/probP"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/length"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Enter the number of servers:"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/server"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text='Please enter a length of time:'
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/length"
            android:layout_below="@+id/speed"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Ouput"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/Output"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Enter" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivty.java:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        output= (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.Output);
        server =(EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.server);
        length = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.length);
        speed = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.speed);
        probR = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.probR);
        probP = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.probP);
    }
    TextView output;
    EditText server;
    EditText length;
    EditText speed;
    EditText probP;
    EditText probR;

    public void add(View view)
    {

       int nServer= Integer.parseInt(server.getText().toString());
        int nLength = Integer.parseInt(length.getText().toString());
        int nSpeed = Integer.parseInt(speed.getText().toString());
        int p= Integer.parseInt(probP.getText().toString());
        int r = Integer.parseInt(probR.getText().toString());
        int addAll = nServer+nLength+nSpeed+p+r;
        print(addAll);


    }
      public void print(int a)
    {
        output.setText(a);
    }



}
```

I thought it was maybe it has something wrong doing Integer.parse().
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NumberFormatException and how can I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849984/what-is-a-numberformatexception-and-how-can-i-fix-it)

Comment: change `output.setText(a);` to `output.setText(a+"");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all EditText you had set the text. Try to use hint instead of text for all edittexts

```
android:text="Enter the number of servers:"
```

to

```
android:hint="Enter the number of servers:"
```

and put all Interger parsing inside try catch block

```
try {
  int nServer= Integer.parseInt(server.getText().toString());
    int nLength = Integer.parseInt(length.getText().toString());
    int nSpeed = Integer.parseInt(speed.getText().toString());
    int p= Integer.parseInt(probP.getText().toString());
    int r = Integer.parseInt(probR.getText().toString());
    int addAll = nServer+nLength+nSpeed+p+r;
    print(addAll);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
   //alert the user that the number they tried to enter was invalid
 }
```

Comment: i updated the error log to when i input 1s only without Text

Comment: @jackie chen While setting text to textview it needs to be string

Comment: change `output.setText(a);` to `output.setText(a+"");`

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, it does have to do with `Integer.parse()`. You can determine this by examining the following line from your stack trace:

`Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1Enter the number of servers:"`

This means that your `Integer.parse()` method was trying to convert "1Enter the number of servers:" into an integer, which is obviously incorrect. Now looking closer at your code, it looks like your "server" `EditText` field contains the text "Enter the number of servers:". This line in your code:

`int nServer= Integer.parseInt(server.getText().toString());`

gets the text from that "server" field, and tries to convert it into an integer. You likely entered the value "1", and did not clear the default text from that field. This caused the value of `server.getText().toString()` to be "1Integer the number of servers:". This means that `Integer.parse()` will throw a `NumberFormatException`, since that is not a valid integer. What you should do is handle this `NumberFormatException`, because you cannot always guarantee that your users will type in a valid number. This would look something like:

```
try {
  int nServer= Integer.parseInt(server.getText().toString());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  //alert the user that the number they tried to enter was invalid
}
```

Comment: i tried deleting the textfield and just putting in numbers , but it still crashes

Comment: @jackiechen What error did you get when you replaced the text in that field with a number?

Comment: @jackiechen It looks like you have a different error now. Looking at your new stacktrace: `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x5
` is the relevant line. What I think might be happening is that you are trying to set an integer value to a string field. Does your xml for the server text field look something like this now: `android:text=5
`? If so, try putting quotes around the 5, like this: `android:text="5"
`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388586/android-content-res-resourcesnotfoundexception-string-resource-id for more info.

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1Enter
>   the number of servers:"

You can parse only numbers to integer.There is String inputs in the text field which is named server..