# how to check multiple checkboxes in a custom listview

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView for which I have created a custom_row in xml. My custom_row contains an ImageView, 2 Textviews and a Checkbox.
Data source for the listView is right now 3 arrays i.e. MedName, Descrip and Image of Meds.

Now, when the app runs so the ListView fills up with data from Array.

**Question:** I want to allow the user to select as many medicines (via checkbox) as possible and when the submit button is pressed so all the selected (checked) items will be stored in separate table and unchecked in a separate table. BUT right now I've not attached any database so I want to display these checked and unchecked items in Toast.

This is my custom_row (customlayout) code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="15sp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv1"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="90dp"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/iv1"
    android:layout_marginStart="90dp"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cbTaken"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvDescription"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvDescription"
    android:text="Taken" />
```

**And this is my MainActivity code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView lv1;
CheckBox cbTaken;

int imgs[] = {R.drawable.flagyl, R.drawable.imodium, R.drawable.flagyl, R.drawable.imodium};
String[] medicinename = {"Flagyl", "Imodium", "Flagyl", "Imodium"};
String[] usage = {"Gas Trouble", "Diarrohea", "Gas Trouble", "Diarrohea"};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lv1 = findViewById(R.id.lvCustom);
    cbTaken = findViewById(R.id.cbTaken);

    CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter();
    lv1.setAdapter(customAdapter);

}

public void showToast(View view) {

    String status = "";

    if (cbTaken.isChecked())
    {
        status = "Taken";
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, status, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}


class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{

    @Override
    public int getCount() { // used for size of our Data
        return imgs.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {


        return 0;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customlayout, null); 

        ImageView imgView= view.findViewById(R.id.iv1); //Now our layout is in View so we search inside view
        TextView tvName = view.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        TextView tvDesc = view.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);

        // NOW WE BIND THE DATA WITH IMageView

        imgView.setImageResource(imgs[i]);
        tvName.setText("Med Name: " + medicinename[i]);
        tvDesc.setText("Usage: " + usage[i]);

        return view;
    }

}
```

}

This is the screenshot of running App[CustomListView App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUCIT.png)

I don't know how to add code in add comments options therefore I'm adding comments after @ManxDev reply here:
This is what I have done

```
It is crashing my App
cbTaken.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

                if (cbTaken.isChecked())
                {
                    int posi = lv1.getSelectedItemPosition();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, posi, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: see [List11](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List11.java) from `ApiDemos`

Answer (score 0):

Each element in your listview has it's own checkbox, you should add an onclicklistener for the checkbox inside the getView method

```
@Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customlayout, null);

        ImageView imgView= view.findViewById(R.id.iv1); //Now our layout is in View so we search inside view
        TextView tvName = view.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        TextView tvDesc = view.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);

        // NOW WE BIND THE DATA WITH IMageView

        imgView.setImageResource(imgs[i]);
        tvName.setText("Med Name: " + medicinename[i]);
        tvDesc.setText("Usage: " + usage[i]);

        final CheckBox cb = view.findViewById(R.id.cbTaken);
        cb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(cb.isChecked()){
                    //do your stuff here
                    //in your case you might want to add tvName.getText().toString() to a table which stores all the names of checked items.
                }else{
                    //remove tvName.getText().toString() from the table which stores checked items
                }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
```

and when submit button is clicked just traverse through the list where you stored all the selected items.

Comment: Thank you for your contriutions.
@Srijay, the point after if condition I need to get the position of the Listview Item for which I need position parameter which comes under setOnItemClickListener but here I don't have that event. So how do I get listView properties inside this OnClickListener?

Comment: @user87 the variable i should give the position

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Listener in your CustomAdapter.getView to the Checkbox.

Then when checkbox is checked display a Toast containing the information of that ListItem. You'll need to pass Context to your CustomAdapter.

```
cBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {

       }
   }
);
```

Comment: Sorry you want a CheckBox not CompoundButton. 

I've updated my answer

Comment: I've added new piece of code as you directed in my original question. But its crashing the App ManxDev

Comment: How do I add the error. Its loooong error in Android Monitor?

Comment: There should be a line that says "Caused by xxxxx Exception"

Comment: --------- beginning of crash
11-22 11:06:40.311 3181-3181/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.durrani.customlistview, PID: 3181
                                                 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xffffffff

Comment: Check this answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388586/android-content-res-resourcesnotfoundexception-string-resource-id/17388587

Comment: at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:338)
                                                     at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:304)
                                                     at com.durrani.customlistview.MainActivity$MyCustomAdapter$1.onCheckedChanged(MainActivity.java:117)
 at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:171)
                                                     at android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle(CompoundButton.java:127)

Comment: This line No. 117 is
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, posi, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: Ok ManxDev, I have found the error (exception and solved it) Now what I want that when I click on Checkbox so the medicine name which is written in textView is displayed in my Toast?

Comment: Create a toast in the OnCheckedChanged.

You need to give the toast the Context you passed to the CustomAdapter.