# Xamarin.Android : Problem using the library Zxing,Net.Mobile, error (Message=Resource ID #0x7f0a002a) in the debug before inflate the AXML

Tags: android-fragments, xamarin.android, zxing, barcode-scanner, zxing.net.mobile

I have a problem using the library Zxing,Net.Mobile,  want to have a popup (fragment) which reads a barcode, but in debug I get an error, I'm using the following repository as an example (https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/tree/master/Samples/Sample.Android), but when I run the code and click to open the fragment I get the following problem.

This is my AXML Activity (**OrdersPatientsActivity**)

[image: OrdersPatientsActivity]

When I click on the red highlighted button, it opens my popup (ScanBarcodeFragment), but in the Activity I initialise Zxing as follows (the final part):

```
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your application here
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.LayoutListOrdenPatient);
            searchBar = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.searchBarMainFilterCarMed);
            llPatientInfo = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.llPatientInfo);
            PatientName = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvPatientNameCarMed);
            IdentificationType = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvTDocumentoCarMed);
            Identification = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvDocumentoCarMed);
            Age = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvEdadCarMed);
            HistoryNumber = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvHistoriaCarMed);
            EntryNumber = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvNoIngresoCarMed);
            Location = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvUbicacionCarMed);
            btnExpandView = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.btnExpandView);
            btnScanMed = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.btnScanMed);
            ListMedicamentCarMed = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.ListMedicamentCarMed);
            Save = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnGuardar);
            ///vista cargando
            var ProgressView = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.LoadingDialogCharge, null);
            TextView Msg = ProgressView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvProgressDialogMsg);
            Msg.Text = "Cargando información de los cargos...";
            animationscale = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(this, Resource.Drawable.Animationlogo);
            LogoDialogProgress = ProgressView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.LogoDialogProgress);
            progressDialog = (new AlertDialog.Builder(this, Resource.Style.ServinteDialog)).Create();
            progressDialog.SetView(ProgressView);

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.Android.Platform.Init();

            ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner.Initialize(Application);


            btnScanMed.Click += BtnScanMed_Click;
}
```

> ```
>       Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
>       global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
>       ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.Android.Platform.Init();
>       ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner.Initialize(Application);
> ```

And in the click the ImageView is this:

```
                     try
                    {
                        StartActivity(typeof(ScanBarcodeFragment));
                    }
```

the fragment is exactly as in the example:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using ZXing.Mobile;

namespace APPDroid.CarMed.Fragments
{
    [Activity(Label = "ZXing.Net.Mobile", Theme = "@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light", ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.KeyboardHidden)]
    public class ScanBarcodeFragment : AndroidX.Fragment.App.FragmentActivity
    {
        #region Variables

        ZXingScannerFragment scanFragment;
        #endregion
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ScanBarcode);
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();


            if (scanFragment == null)
            {
                scanFragment = new ZXingScannerFragment();

                SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Replace(Resource.Id.fragment_container, scanFragment).Commit();
            }

            Scan();
        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)
        => Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        protected override void OnPause()
        {
            scanFragment?.StopScanning();

            base.OnPause();
        }
        void Scan()
        {
            var opts = new MobileBarcodeScanningOptions
            {
                PossibleFormats = new List<ZXing.BarcodeFormat> {
                    ZXing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE
                },
                CameraResolutionSelector = availableResolutions =>
                {

                    foreach (var ar in availableResolutions)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Resolution: " + ar.Width + "x" + ar.Height);
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            };

            scanFragment.StartScanning(result =>
            {

                // Null result means scanning was cancelled
                if (result == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Text))
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "Scanning Cancelled", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                    return;
                }

                // Otherwise, proceed with result
                RunOnUiThread(() => Toast.MakeText(this, "Scanned: " + result.Text, ToastLength.Short).Show());
            }, opts);
        }
    }
}
```

But I get this error when I click on it:
[image: Infalte Correct]

when inflating the view all goes well, but when finishing the Scan() method; the problem occurs:

[image: screenshot the problem]

> Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException Message=Resource ID #0x7f0a002a

Is it possible that I need an extra textview with a result ID?

Please I need help I have been trying to do barcode scanning for several days.

Comment: It seems you copy all the code from the sample code. You could check the link below about this error message. It may be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388586/android-content-res-resourcesnotfoundexception-string-resource-id

Comment: Yes and no, I have tried to implement for now that only open the view, which according to the repo should work, customization is done later in terms of the view, I will read what you passed me, but it should still work if you notice that is what they say "works".

Comment: I tested the code in the Github provided by Redth. It works for me. If you still have issue for this, could you provided a code sample for me to reproduce?